# What is dab_db?

Tags: php, content-management-system

a1cms, an obscure CMS written in PHP, uses a function `dab_db` in a few modules, but never defines it (I checked it with grep). The invocation goes something like this:

```php
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$f = $_POST['f'];
$f['name'] = dab_db($f['name']);
$f['about'] = dab_db($f['about']);
$f['date'] = dab_db($f['date']);
$f['showing'] = (isset($f['showing'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

Does anybody know what is this function or have any ideas on what it might do? Any idea is good, in the worst case I'll attempt to reverse engineer it.

UPD: I have a feeling that it does input sanitation. Does it fit that pattern?

Comment: It's not a function in the PHP core nor in any module I know, and Googling seems to confirm that. My bet is the CMS *is* defining it somewhere.

Comment: Using a not-so-obscure CMS is not an option?

Comment: Is this a paid for or a free CMS? If it's free maybe you can tell us where to get it and we can take a look at it.

Comment: I guess it's paid but it's very close to abandonware :) Anyways, my guess was correct, it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a default PHP function (which could be guessed from the ~75 Google hits), so it must be defined somewhere. Does the CMS contain obfuscated (Zend, ionCube) code which could contain the function `dab_db`?

You could throw in a few types of input and see what happens, it looks like some kind of escape function which you could replace by `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I defined dab_db as striptags and escape_string, it works now. Thanks :)